# Impossible Spherical Coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

This was a question from Indian IIT exam and had 3% solve rate, see if you can solve it within 5 minutes.

Region given by $9 \le x^2+y^2 \le 81$ and $0 \le z \le \sqrt (x^2 + y^2)$

Create a triple integral (volume) by cylindrical coordinates (easy) than attempt to render with spherical.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is the question, exactly? The title does not match the body. Which coordinate system do you want the answer in?

Comment: @NinadMunshi This is exact wording from IIT exam. Basically conduct the triple integral using cylindrical coordinates first and show boundaries, then do the same with spherical coordinates. I am simply giving the title to prepare you for the difficulty of the latter.

Comment: I see. I have my answer in both coordinate systems below.

Comment: If you would like a challenge, I would encourage you to try to find a way to write the integral for the volume inside both spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2 = 1$ with only one integral in spherical coordinates. If you can set up that integral, you can set up any integral in polar coordinate systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cylindrical:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_3^9 \int_0^r rdzdrd\theta$$

In spherical:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{3\csc\phi}^{9\csc\phi} \rho^2 \sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

The second is easy to derive from the first, just use the fact that $r = \rho\sin\phi$ and a small sketch in the $rz$-plane to identify the easiest order of integration.

Comment: Since $z\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ it should be $0\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}4$ according to the usual notation.

Comment: @user that is not correct. The $z=0$ plane is given by $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$ See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) I switched the names of the angles in accordance to how they show up in introductory textbooks, but the $rz$ angle is always defined relative to the $z$ axis, not the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Ah ok you are taking $0\le \phi \le \pi$ from above. It's fine. I've considered $-\pi/2\le \phi \le \pi/2$.

Comment: @user I edited my comment for clarity. And nothing wrong with defining your own coordinate system! But one should always stick with a known standard when someone refers to a coordinate system by name.

Comment: That's fine, I've also added some more detail on that. The second notation is usually used in [geography context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#In_geography).

Comment: @user there is still a slight discrepancy between your two answers. I've noticed that Ninad used csc in the boundaries, and user used secant. Which is correct?

Comment: @chanlee both are correct in their own answers. Our $\phi$ are off by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi\right) = \csc\phi$

Comment: Both are correct, we are using different angles for $\phi$. My notation follows the sketch. The notation from Ninad is from positive $z$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course and, with reference to the notation give in the sketch, the limits should be

- $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$
- $0\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}4\quad$
- $\frac 3{\cos \phi}\le r \le \frac 9{\cos \phi}$

[image]